# Is it necessary to add fast recovery diode parallel to MOSFET in inverter that is designed for motor driving?

Tags: mosfet, inverter

[image]

The line current of the load will be maximum 20 A and the MODFET [IRFB4110](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809192210_Infineon-Technologies-IRFB4110PBF_C2650.pdf) has body diode which can easily conduct this current. According to datasheet the body diode should carry 170 A (depending on the heat sink). I have also placed a fast recovery diode [(VS-30ETH06-M3)](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1912192111_Vishay-Intertech-VS-30ETH06-M3_C468083.pdf) in my design having 20 A average rectified current rating. The problem is that it is increasing the board size a lot (also increasing the Bill Of material). I need to know is it bad to get rid of the fast recovery diodes in this design? Circuit will drive a single motor.

Comment: This site is not showing the schematic

Comment: It looks just fine? Might be a browser issue.

Comment: Is the body diode good enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MOSFET's body diode has a **typical** reverse recovery time of 60 ns at a temperature of 125° C whereas the external diode recovery is **typically** 77 ns hence, it doesn't look like the diode is bringing much to the party unless you have a special reason for keeping it that you haven't disclosed.

[image]

It's not even close when it comes to diode losses either: -

[image]

At 20 amps, the MOSFET's diode drops around 0.6 volts whereas the external diode drops about 1.5 volts. There are no compelling reasons that I can see to use the external diode.